# How to Create a Django Model Instance That Contains a Required OneToOneField with DRF Serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, one-to-one, django-serializer

### The Question

Let's say I have a model that contains a `OneToOneField` like so:

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model)
    # some basic fields...

class EventDetail(models.Model):
    event = models.OneToOneField(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                          related_name='event_detail')
    # other basic fields, all with default values...
```

**What is a proper way to implement a POST request that intends to create a new `Event` in the database that automatically creates a default EventDetail linked to it if it is None in the request header, using Django Rest Framework's Serializers?**

### My Attempt

**test.py**

```
class EventTestCase(APITestCase):
    def test_post(self):
        # Need to provide an id, or else an error occurs about the OneToOneField
        event = Event(id=1)
        serializer = serializers.EventSerializer(event)
        res = self.api_client.post('/event/', serializer.data)
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = EventSerializer(
        data=request.data)
    # ***This always returns false!***
    if serializer.is_valid():
        try:
            instance = serializer.save()
        except ValueError:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serialization_title = "Event"
    event_detail = EventDetailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = ('id',)
        error_status_codes = {
            HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: 'Bad Request'
        }

class EventDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serialization_title = "Event Detail"

    class Meta:
        model = models.EventDetail
        exclude = ('id',)
        error_status_codes = {
            HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: 'Bad Request'
        }
```

As noted in a comment above, `serializer.is_valid()` always returns false with the error:

> {'event_detail': [u'This field may not be null.']}

I understand that this is complaining because both `EventDetail` and `Event` need to be created in order for a OneToOne relationship to be added, but how do you deal with this using Serializers when a OneToOneField is required and yet not provided by the client?

Thank you for your help.

Disclaimer: I am using Django 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the `EventDetailSerializer` with `read_only=True` or `required=False` and then handle the creation of the `EventDetail` in different ways, for example: you could have a `post_save` signal that listens to the `Event` class - once a new `Event` object has been created, you can then create the initial `EventDetail` object, or you perform this creation after your `serializer.save()` on the `post` definition, or even on your `create` method of your `EventSerializer`.

edit: an example on how you could perform the creation using the `EventDetailSerializer` and overriding the `create` method of your `EventSerializer`.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    detail = self.initial_data.get('event_detail')
    instance = super().create(validated_data)
    if detail:
        serializer = EventDetailSerializer(data=detail)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(event=instance)
    return instance
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - there's definitely a lot of promise to the suggestions you propose, and `serializer.is_valid()` is returning True with those two fields you specified on the serializer. Can you elaborate on why those meet the needs I'm looking for? According to the docs (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/), if I make it read-only, it "should not be included in the input during create or update operations." I am still looking to allow an `Event` that has an `EventDetail` linked to it. Would this still work in this case?

Comment: Can you also explain your suggestion of setting `required=False`? According to the docs, this seems to deal with omitting the field from the output when serializing, or when deserializing. Thanks again.

Comment: so basically, by setting it to `read_only`, it tells your `EventSerializer` that the `EventDetailSerializer` will only be used when reading that data - so it's gonna get ignored when receiving data from outside. and yes, this still allows you to receive an `Event` that has an `EventDetail` linked by it, but you're gonna need to handle the `EventDetail` creation manually, since modelserializers do not support `nested serializer writing` (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers). you can achieve that by overriding the `create` method.

Comment: The code that you pasted indeed allows me to create an Event with an optional EventDetail parameter! Looking at the URL you reference above, I noticed that the line, `instance = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)` as suggested by the docs fails for me, throwing an assert of the DRF source code: `create() did not return an object instance,` as far as I can tell. Can you explain why your `instance = super().create(validated_data)` works in contrast?

Comment: the error you're getting is literally because your implementation of the `create` method wasn't returning an instance, you need to the return the instance that has been created at the end of the create method, hence the `return instance` on my code.

Comment: Hm... unfortunately that is not the case. The program throws an assert exactly on the line of code: `instance = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)` when stepping into it. For now, however, your suggested code suffices. Thank you!